# .CER & .PFX file formats

Tags: certificate, x509certificate2

Since not all the UWP environments support the Windows CAPI and Win32 APIs necessary to create .CER and .PFX files. I was wondering if anyone in the community knew of a library or open source project that does this programmatically and without the use of any Windows, Unix or iOS native APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with .cer and .pfx certificates with uwp and there is not a third party library or open source project to create these kind of files. There is only support for reading

Comment: RicardoPons,

I think I was clear in that we all know there is no support thus far in UWP.  I'm asking about any knowledge of libraries or open source projects *OUT SIDE* of UWP so that someone like me can build it for UWP.  I'll also take a white paper on the file format and structure too.  Anything that will help me understand how to make these files myself.